# Android Studio genegare SHA2 APK

Tags: android, android-studio, sha256

I can generate signed SHA1 APK on Android Studio and also can convert to SHA256 APK using **jarsigner** and **zipalign 4**, which is a 2 steps solution.

Is there any way to build **SHA256 APK**, same as SHA1 with android studio or any gradlew command depends on gradle configutaion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean the keystore SHA256 signature?

Comment: No I already have SHA256 Keystore.Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA.
I need a simple way to generate APK with SHA256 fingerprint

Comment: Hi @user2817947 Can you  please share the steps to follows or any link which will help us sign the app using SHA256?